# datagrid item template event registration failed

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, itemtemplate

Hi I've a datagrid with Item template. Some thing like

```
<asp:templatecolumn itemstyle-wrap="False" headertext="EmpID">
                        <itemtemplate>
                            <span style="cursor:hand;text-decoration:underline;" onmouseover="this.style.color='#4D6186';" onmouseout="this.style.color='black';" onclick="SelectEmp(this,'<%# txtGUID %>','<%# txtName %>',false);"><%# Container.DataItem("EmpID")%></span>
                        </itemtemplate>
                    </asp:templatecolumn>
```

When I try to bind the data (55000 rows) to datagrid it is not showing any data and cursor is showing busy status. When I remove onclick, onmouseover, onmouseout events, it is working fine.

My question is, is there any limitation for data binding to a grid when dynamic events are there.

Or Am I doing any mistake over here? I'm struggling to find out the solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please check this line of code:

```
onclick="SelectEmp(this,'<%# txtGUID %>','<%# txtName %>',false);"
```

I think you are you trying to get a variable or property txtGUID and txtName, try

```
onclick="SelectEmp(this,'<%= txtGUID) %>','<%= txtName %>',false);"
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your response... but the same code is working when I tried to bind around 1500 records. If my db is having more than 1500 records it is not working. Any specific reason?